# Overriding a tag height element

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin

In our application we use the vaadin table but we applied our internal changements.
Is there a way to change the specified height value in the highlited tag (blue) only for this table (not to all application tables):

```
<div style="height: 344px;" class="v-table-body-noselection">
```

See attached picture:

[image: HeightValue]

The table has 2 main elements, the header and the body:

Here's the body tag :

```
      <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; height: 344px; width: 
       873px;" class="v-scrollable v-table-body-wrapper v-table-body" tabindex="-1">
```

I want to edit the the following element value:

```
height: 344px;
```

Is there a way to do it with css by editing the style.less file.

Comment: Can you edit the html and give it a id?

Comment: I don't know how to do it really :/

Comment: Have you tried using table.setHeight("344px");

Comment: @AmiraGL Did you tried the thing Chris said? Did it work or do you still need help?

Comment: @PatrickMlr no it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this help you but try this:

```
table.addStyleName("components-inside");
```

CSS

```
.components-inside {
        height: 54px;
}
```

[Found on vaadin.com](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html)

Is this what you're searching for?